Finding the interior of a set of continuous functions
Let $C[0,1]$ be the family of continuous functions on $[0,1]$ with the
norm $||x||_{\infty}=\max\limits_{0\leq t\leq 1}|x(t)|.$ Let
$A=\{x\in C[0,1]| ||x||_{\infty}\leq 1, x(1)=1\}.$  Prove that
$A$ is closed and bounded. Find $\text{Int}A$.
I already prove $A$ is closed and bounded since $A\subset B(0,2)$, $0\in C[0,1]$. I'm stuck at finding $\text{Int}A$. $x\in\text{Int}A\iff\exists r>0: B(x,r)\subset A$. How to find $\text{Int}A$.

Interior is empty. Hint: $(1-\frac 1 n)x \to x$.

@geetha290krm could you explain why we need to consider $(1-\frac{1}{n})x$?

@freakish My definition for Int(A) is that $x\in A\iff\exists r>0: B(x,r)\subset A$. I don't understand which criterion you're using to find Int(A)?

@geetha290krm Could I ask which criterion you're using to find $\text{Int(A)}$?

If $x \in Int(A)$ then $B(x,r) \subset A$ for some $r>0$.  I am saying that $(1-\frac  1n)x \in B(x,r)$ but $(1-\frac  1n) x \notin A$ for $n$ sufficiently large.

@geetha290krm Got it! Thank you

@freakish you helped me understand. Thanks

We'll be using a bit easier characterization of the interior:

Lemma. Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $A\subseteq X$. Then $x\in Int(A)$ if and only if for any sequence $(x_n)\subseteq X$ such that $x_n\to x$ there is $M$ such that $x_n\in A$ whenever $n>M$. Or in other words: any sequence convergent to $x$ is eventually in $A$.

Proof. "$\Rightarrow$" if $x\in Int(A)$, then there is $r>0$ such that $B(x,r)\subseteq A$. But then if $x_n\to x$ then there is $M$ such that $d(x_n,x)<r$ whenever $n>M$. And so $x_n\in B(x,r)\subseteq A$ eventually.
"$\Leftarrow$" By contradiction assume that $x\not\in Int(A)$. This means that for any $n$ the open ball $B(x,1/n)$ is not contained in $A$. In other words for any $n$ there is $x_n\in B(x,1/n)$ such that $x_n\not\in A$. But then $d(x_n,x)<1/n$ and so $x_n\to x$, which contradicts our assumption. $\Box$

With this we can show that your $A$ has empty interior. Indeed, consider $f\in A$ and define
$$f_n:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$$
$$f_n(x)=(1-1/n)\cdot f(x)$$
It is not hard to see that $f_n\to f$ in the sup metric/norm. However $f_n(1)=1-1/n$ and therefore $f_n\not\in A$. And so by our lemma $f\not\in Int(A)$. Since we chose $f$ arbitrarily, then the only possible conclusion is that $Int(A)=\emptyset$.
